# joining Tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I'm trying to join 2 tables in Sql Server 2008

I have a Primary Key staffId in my Staff table, it is also a Foreign Key in the Call table(Called Assigned Staff), how do I get the Assigned Staff Column in the Call table to display The Name field of the Staff Table based on the Foreign Key?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Also, what have you tried? What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT S.NameColumn, S.Any_Other_Column, AStf.Any_Other_Column, .... so on
FROM Staff S INNER JOIN [Assigned Staff] AStf
ON S.StaffId = AStf.StaffId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about MS SQL or Entity Framework Database First, then you can:

- use [computed sql column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345330%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which becomes entity property with computed StoreGeneratedPattern (*use custom user-defined function to get what you need from referenced table*);
- or populate your entities with custom sql/call sql: see [Use StoredProcs](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/call-store-procedure-from-entity-framework/), [Use DefiningQuery](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/05/14/how-why-use-definingquery-element.aspx), [Call Model-Defined Functions in Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx), [Call Model-Defined Functions as Object Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456845.aspx)

If you talking about Entity Framework Code First, see [Calculated Column CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/entity-framework-calculated-column-codefirst)