# azure sql indexing strategy on datetime fields

Tags: sql, indexing, azure-sql-database

I have two `datetimeoffset` fields in table (sql azure),  `Migrated` and `Updated`

I usually do this search `select * from table where Migrated < Updated`

What would be the right strategy for indexing these fields?

1. two indexes, one for each field
2. one index on `Migrated`, `Updated`
3. one index on `Updated`, `Migrated`

Table is huge and requires indexing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most versions of SQL Server, you can take the following approach.  I have not tried this in SQL Azure.

Create a computed column and then an index on that:

```
alter table t add MigratedToUpdatedTime as (datediff(seconds, Migrated, Updated))

create index t_MigratedToUpdatedTime on t(MigratedToUpdatedTime);
```

Then in your `where` clause, you can do:

```
where MigratedToUpdatedTime > 0;
```

Comment: That helps. !!! I also used these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/calculated-column-in-ef-code-first and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/calculated-column-in-ef-code-first to implement idea proposed by Gordon