# Entity Framework update field after a condition is met in an automated way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework code-first and ASP.NET MVC in C#. I have a table:

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    public bool Active{ get; set; }

}
```

My question is, given the above fields, how do I update the `Active` field, after the `EndDate` passed?

For instance, the end date is 08/04/2018 and today is 08/05/2018, then Active=false.

Please take into account that performance is important in this case. Each user creates a project that other users can see.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aiming at some automated/scheduled manner to update this field?

Comment: Yes dear Arnold, I would like it to be automated or scheduled.

Comment: Then you should be more specific. There are many ways to do that. It would be great if you could share some first attempts at achieving this.

Comment: **IMHO**, some (simpler) scheduled task (as commented above) to say, run a `sproc`, sounds good (no need to force/complicate things with some EF/app bound way).

Comment: If you don't really need the value of `Active` in the database, you can turn it into a read-only property (by removing the setter) and make it return `if (EndDate > DateTime.Now ? true : false);` or just `(EndDate > DateTime.Now);`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the Active value is used in the database to filter the active projects

Comment: @EdSF can you please suggest some kind of stored procedure in the answer? I am using entity framework  for this project. I know I can import a sproc, but can I make it run in an automated fashion?

Comment: Use a computed column in the database to return either 0 or 1 based on `GetDate` or `GetUtcDate` (or equivalent) compared to `EndDate`. See also [Calculated column in EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15585330/1260204)

Comment: can you please write an answer? so I can vote it. Thank you

Comment: this doesn't sound like something you'd want to be done by the database, since this field can change at any time. I would simply ignore this property in the database model and write the getter to implement the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `Active` field a computed column.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]
public bool Active { get { return [condition goes here]; } }
```

Comment: You're right about database-generated, but not about the condition in the getter. It should be a standard getter because, well, the database generates the value.

Comment: hello, I like what you have here, however the active field will be used for some entity framework queries. For instance, filter where active is true

Comment: @GertArnold can you specify more about this?

Comment: The database field `Active` should be a [computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585492/861716). Then all EF does is read its value.

Answer (score 2):

This *isn't* the only way. Use one that suits your needs/resources (what you have access to - e.g. SQL Server Agent). This takes things away from EF/application (everything in this sample is done in SQL Server).

A simplistic stored procedure could be:

```
// Expire after current date
UPDATE [insert your table name here] 
SET Active = 0 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, EndDate, GETDATE()) > 0;
```

Yes, you can [schedule a stored procedure to run as a `JOB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017)

So assuming you named the stored procedure `UpdateStatus`, your job `command` would be `EXEC dbo.UpdateStatus`.

Hth...